# What is the "kaluad" process on Linux?

Tags: linux, process, background-process

I have been browsing running processes on my PC, and I found a process with a name "kaluad", at the time with PID 196 running under root with priority -20. I can't find it in any documentation, man page for this or any similar name does not exist, `/proc/196/exe` does not link anywhere and `/proc/196/attr` does not return anything, it's just empty.

The process behaves like a ghost and even after searching online I could not find a single line of documentation, the only thing I could find are tons of ps or top dumps which include this process, so many other people have it running on their computers as well.

Does anyone know what does this process perform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kaluad` is the [SCSI multipath ALUA](http://www.linux-iscsi.org/wiki/Asymmetric_Logical_Unit_Assignment) (asymmetric logical unit assignment) [workqueue](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/scsi/device_handler/scsi_dh_alua.c). It’s used to handle delayed work — basically, whenever an operation produces a “retry” result, it is added to the workqueue for later handling (look for `queue_delayed_work` in the source code linked above).